# PHP code breaking HTML layout

Tags: php, html, layout

I have a simple file uploader, which thanks to stackoverflow is now fully working, however when I copied the PHP code across to my main layout, once initialised to upload a file, but it is wrong format or size and it echos the error, it breaks the HTML below it. Im thinking its to do with the "exit;" after each echo? but could be wrong.

```
<?php
if($_POST['upload']) {
if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "")
{
    #there's no file name return an error
    echo "<br/><b>Please select a file to upload!\n</b>";
    exit;
}
#we have a filename, continue

#directory to upload to
$uploads = '/home/habbonow/public_html/other/quacked/photos';
$usruploads = 'photos';

#allowed file types
$type_array = array(image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_JPEG), image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_GIF), image_type_to_mime_type(IMAGETYPE_PNG), 'image/pjpeg');

if(!in_array($_FILES['image']['type'], $type_array))
{
    #the type of the file is not in the list we want to allow
    echo "<br/><b>That file type is not allowed!\n</b>";
    exit;
}

$max_filesize = 512000;
$max_filesize_kb = ($max_filesize / 1024);

if($_FILES['image']['size'] > $max_filesize)
{
    #file is larger than the value of $max_filesize return an error
    echo "<br/><b>Your file is too large, files may be up to ".$max_filesize_kb."kb\n</b>";
    exit;
}

$imagesize = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);

#get width
$imagewidth = $imagesize[0];
#get height
$imageheight = $imagesize[1];

#allowed dimensions
$maxwidth = 1024;
$maxheight = 1024;

if($imagewidth > $maxwidth || $imageheight > $maxheight)
{
    #one or both of the image dimensions are larger than the allowed sizes return an error
    echo "<br/><b>Your file is too large, files may be up to ".$maxwidth."px x ".$maxheight."px in size\n</b>";
    exit;
}

move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploads.'/'.$_FILES['image']['name']) or die ("Couldn't upload ".$_FILES['image']['name']." \n");

echo "<br/>The URL to your photo is <b>" . $usruploads . "/" . $_FILES['image']['name'] . "</b>. Please use this when defining the gallery photos";

}

?>

<form name="uploader" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input type="file" name="image" style="width:300px;cursor:pointer" />
      <input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload Image" />
</form>
```

Comment: `exit;` will stop the script. HTML after the PHP code will not be send to the browser.

Comment: what error it gives?? pleas mention all

Comment: working perfect here only `move_uploaded_file()` warning after click on upload button bcoz folder structure is different than my pc

Comment: @diEcho,
it does work perfect but the layout i have put it in that i created it breaks at the "exit;". if just on a normal white blank page it works fine due to no formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, when you call `exit`; it means "immediately stop all processing; this script is finished." Anything that comes after it — including HTML — will not be interpreted.

A better organization would be to make this code a function, to the effect of:

```
function uploadMyStuffPlease() {

    if($_POST['upload']) {
        if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "")
        {
            #there's no file name return an error
            echo "<br/><b>Please select a file to upload!\n</b>";
            return;
        }
        #we have a filename, continue

    // ....

}
```

Now you can simply call `uploadMyStuffPlease()`, which will do as much processing as it can, and perhaps return early in the event of an error. Either way, the function **will** return, and so the rest of your script (including that HTML) can still be interpreted.

Comment: as in:
`code`<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadMyStuffPlease() {
        
        <?php
if($_POST['upload']) {
if($_FILES['image']['name'] == "")
{
    #there's no file name return an error
    echo "<br/><b>Please select a file to upload!\n</b>";
    return;
}`code`

etc.......

then:
`code`<form name="uploader" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="uploadMyStuffPlease()">`code`

Comment: This isn't JavaScript. The `<script>` tag is not involved here. Simply include the function wherever in your PHP you have the code now.

Comment: :o didnt know php had functions!! 
however it doesnt work at all now, no even erroring.
<form name="uploader" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return uploadMyStuffPlease()">

Comment: Much better than echo store the message into variable and use it in presentation layer

Comment: Again, you cannot call a server-side function with an `onsubmit` property. Simply call `uploadMyStuffPlease();` from your script (immediately after the bottom of the function would work fine).

Comment: ahhha! got it working! and learned about ising function within PHP.
thanks very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you call `exit;` your PHP script won't be able to output **anything** anymore. That's why the layout is broken.

You should maybe try to keep the HTML parts out of your PHP code and especially avoid opening tags that you don't close afterwards (i.e. `div`s or anything).

That being said, it's probably safest to just put everything into a function that won't exit the script when finished (see other's posts).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(isset($_POST['upload'])){
```

OR

```
if(!empty($_POST['upload'])){
```

And remove `exit`...

Comment: doesnt work, if i remove the exits, it just outputs all the echoed errors. thanks tho,

Comment: @ben, have you replaced first line with the one I provided you? I think if you leave `$_POST['upload']` only it checks for boolean value.

Comment: yep i changed that line, i tried both of them, both attempts without exits; and didnt work:)

Comment: Hmmm, try changing that line to `!empty($_FILES['image']['name'])`, and remove `exit`s, try submitting the form without selecting the file.